Could not load file or assembly "System.Runtime" error in Windows Server Env
I migrated a WPF project from .NET Framework to .NET 6 which builds fine on my local system (windows 11). However when I moved forward to Azure pipeline, we got this error and it can be replicated on a Windows Server 2022 VM.
The full error is
Error   LC0000  'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)' ProAnalysisUI   C:\...\ProAnalysisUI\LC 1   

There are several points confuse me:

The error shows missing assembly but "System.Runtime" is not directly used in this project. Only one dependency  includes this assembly and it's compatible to .NET 6. How can I trace where the assembly cause this error?
It shows the error occurs in file LC which I don't see it directly in the file structure. What does this file mean?
Why the error does not exist on my local system windows 11?

Update 1:
After some experiments, I am able to isolate the problem in a third party tool Actipro. There are two ways to integrate this tool. The first way which I used is installing the software and reference the assemblies. It worked fine. Since we are moving to Azure, I had to switch to the second way which is their Nuget Package. It worked fine on my local system but not on the Pipeline/VM. Today I uninstalled my local installation of Actipro and I am seeing the same error on my local machine. So I guess this problem is not related to the VM. Is there a way that a Nuget package reading license info from local storage? Here is a link to their official guide: https://www.actiprosoftware.com/docs/controls/wpf/licensing

System runtime 6 is .net framework 6. You might reference namespaces in there but first thing to check is you reference that correctly in your yml. Is it not on the VM? You need the windows version for wpf.

@Andy Yes I think so. I have other projects targeting the same framework in the same solution. They build without issue on the VM.

Is the .NET6 Runtime with Windows Desktop support installed? That specifically needs to be on the VM. @andy that might have been a typo but .NET6 would be .NET core not Framework. So the runtime for desktop apps would specifically need to be installed on the VM and wouldn't be a standard part of the OS.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-6.0.29-windows-x64-installer

Sorry wait this is a BUILD server not the VM running the app? In that case it just means the right SDK dependencies aren't installed on the build server.

May I assume if the issue was reproducible when building the project on a Windows Server 2022 VM without using pipeline? It seemed more likely to be caused by the lack of required dependency installed in the environment.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Thank you guys for the helps. It seems the problem is not related to the VM or pipeline. I am able to replicate the issue on my local machine now. Please see the update.

@EmperorEto Thank you for the helps. It seems the problem is not related to the VM or pipeline. I am able to replicate the issue on my local machine now. Please see the update.

The problem is caused by an existing .licx file, which is no longer supported by Actipro .NET 6. After removing the file, it works without issue.
